# SpringSecurity error on Wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jboss, wildfly

While log in with spring-security on wildfly i get this error-page:

```
{"timestamp":1464679377206,"status":999,"error":"None","message":"No message available"}
```

after refresh it redirects me on my custom error page. Then if I clear error-link (like that http://myapp/error ->  http://myapp) application works correctly. When I launch this app with spring-boot (not wildfly) there is no such problem.

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

}
```

Thymeleaf login form

```
        <div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" id="anonymous-navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="login">Log in</button>
        </form>
```

Security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/signup", "/add_person").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/images/**");
    }
}
```

After debugging spring class DefaultErrorAttributes, which sends the message I got this error
`FirewalledRequest[ HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /PersonalFinance/error ]]`

I've watched wildfly logs and haven't found anything useful.

[image: debug]

There are some same questions:

- [Spring Security with basic auth redirecting to /error for invalid credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954292/spring-security-with-basic-auth-redirecting-to-error-for-invalid-credentials)
- [Spring Security - Remember Me Authentication Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272157/spring-security-remember-me-authentication-error)

But these answers haven't solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Error occurred cause folder with images was not included to project, but was specified in spring-security configuration. Thus spring didn't find this path and threw an error.